# Show that $ℓ_2(X)$ is Hilbert space for every set $X$

Tags: metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Show that $ℓ_2(X)$ is Hilbert space for every set $X$

I tryed to find a proof for this problem but i couldn't (searched on internet and mathematical books.Can we find a completed proof for this?

Comment: How do you define $l_2(\{"orange", "car", "my dog"\})? $

Comment: lol, maybe you mean $L^2(X, \mathcal M , \mu)$, for every measure space $(X, \mathcal M , \mu)$? If that's the case, you can find it in any standard measure theory text, such as Folland or Rudin or Stein/Shakarchi, etc. The only difficult thing to prove is completeness...

Comment: that's the problem in this exercise. this question does not expain.I thing its says $L^2$

Comment: i will  agree with Shalop maybe it's $L^2(X,M,μ)$

Comment: To an even more delicate point, how do you define $l_2(X)$ for infinite $X$? I assume for *finite* $X$, that is, $\vert X \vert \in \Bbb N$, $l_2(X)$ is just (more or less) $\Bbb F^n$. with $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb F = \Bbb C$, and the usual inner products.  If $X$ is *countable*, choosing an enumeration yields $l_2(X)$ essentially $l_2(\Bbb N)$.  So I guess the kicker is, what do we do with uncountable $X$?  Of course, I think there are some standard answers to this, but I for one would like to see it addressed.  Cheers!

Comment: @Tryss For any set $X$, $\ell^2(X)$ is by definition $L^2(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is counting measure on $X$. That includes the case $X=\{"orange","cat","mydog"\}$

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, this is very standard. For any set $X$, finite or uncountable or whatever, _counting measure_ on $X$ is the measure $\mu$ defined for all $E\subset X$ by $\mu(E)=$ the number of elements of $E$ if $E$ is finite, $\infty$ if $E$ is infinite. Now the definition of $\ell^2(X)$ is $\ell^2(X)=L^2(\mu)$.

Comment: And then it's an easy theorem that _if_ $X$ is countable then $\ell^2(X)$ is what you seem to think it's supposed to be...

Comment: @David C. Ulrich:  I guess your $\infty$ is $\vert \Bbb N \vert$?  Am I on point here?

Comment: @RobertLewis No. The "infinity" that comes up in measure theory is not a cardinality at all! At the very start of the story we choose something that's not a real number, anything at all, and call it $\infty$. We extend the definition of $<$ by saying $x<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, we define the obvious topology on $[0,\infty]$, and now a measure is a map from some sigma-algebra to $[0,\infty]$ satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: @David C. Ulrich:  Yes, of course, now I recall.  My memory of such things is a tad on the rusty side.  So I'm guessing that, without further qualifiations on $X$, like a topology or $\sigma$-algebra, we would take $L^2(X)$ to be the completion of the space of *finite* sequences $X \to \Bbb F$ under the appropriate norm?  My Gawd!  What a monster!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Assuming you meant $\ell^2(X)$ then yes, that's equivalent to the definition I gave.